# Getting created, last accessed and last modified times from locked files in C++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I am currently trying to fix a bug on a legacy application code in which it uses basically [GetFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx) function to retrieve file information through a `HANDLE` obtained by using `CreateFileW` function.

Problem arises when it attempts to work with files that are already opened by other processes like `*.ldf` and `*.mdf` files which are opened by `SQL Server`. An error is thrown when trying to get the file `HANDLE`.

As an alternative, I noticed that `boost` library is being used as a dependency in the project so I found the following code sample working:

```cpp
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

path filePath("path/to/the/file.ext");

std::cout << file_size(filePath) << "\n"; // Getting file size
std::cout << last_write_time(filePath) << "\n"; // Getting write/modified time
```

Using that piece of code we get the file size and the last write time. However, I **still need the created and last accessed times**. Any ideas how can I achieve it?

Comment: Hmm, no, they no doubt welcome a patch from you to add this missing functionality.  Meanwhile, use FindFirstFile() instead.  Do keep in mind that obtaining these properties for files that are hard-locked and continuously updated by the dbase engine is not exactly meaningful, the file size and last access time in particular are very lazily updated.  Surely there's a better way but impossible to guess at without the "why".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost FileSystem doesn't seem to support retrieving the creation/last accessed times for a file.

Under the circumstances, I'd probably use `FindFirstFile` (and `FindClose`) to get the information you want:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA GetFileInfo(char const *path) { 
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;

    HANDLE h;

    h = FindFirstFile(path, &data);
    FindClose(h);
    return data;
}
```

This doesn't require opening the file, so it can retrieve data about a file, even if that file is currently open in another process.